# Bencode in Python with a Debian?

Tags: python, import, installation, bencoding

I'm trying to put bencode on my debian in order to decode some bittorrent data but i don't figure-out how to do it from link like this for exemple:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bencode/1.0

I downloaded the package which correspond to my version that is to say the py2.7 but then i don't know what to do with this zip except unzip it.

My objective is to call bencode in my script with a `from bencode import *` for exemple and use the "decode" like most website show how to do. Unfortunatly it's not the same with the bencode installation insofar as there is no tutorial on internet for it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't download zip files. Install directly from pypi:

```
pip install bencode
```

If you don't have pip, [get it](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html).